# If I try to access a property which is not defined or inherited, its returning empty string. Why such behaviour?

Tags: javascript, function, object

```
function x() {
    console.log(this.name); 
}
x();
```

on executing , console.log will give an empty string.

Is the JavaScript assigns empty value to any property which is not defined or inherited ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are are using function without `new` keyword (not as constructor) `this` points to global object which is `window`. And [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is predefined property identifier, typically empty string by default.

If you used constructor function instead (and you should because your intention is to use own/inherited properties with `this`), your code would have acted as expected giving you `undefined` result:

```
function x() {
    console.log(this.name); // => is indeed "undefined"
}
new x();
```